# How to load a create a login page

Tags: angular, authentication, routes, angular2-routing, angular2-components

i created the following template for the main component of my Angular2 app:

```
<header>
    <topbar></topbar>
</header>

<div class="middle">
    <sidebar></sidebar>
    <main>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

As you can see i put my Angular `router` within the template, under the `main` tag.

Here is my `app.routing.ts` file:

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {Page1Component} from './components/page1/page1.component';
import {Page2Component} from './components/page2/page2.component';
import {Page3Component} from './components/page3/page3.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
  { path: 'page3', component: Page3Component },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Now i want to add a `LoginComponent` that make guest users (= users not logged to the app) not to see the app sections and contents. So the login component should load a page instead of previous template. For example its template could be the following:

```
<header></header>
<div class="welcome">
    <login></login>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

So, how to add it to my routing system and prevent to load other components such as the sidebar, topbar and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Your entry should look like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>    
<footer></footer>
```

And then the login-component is loaded or you main-component which contains all the users should see..

or store the users state in a variable and do something like this:

```
<header>
    <topbar *ngIf="userIsLoggedIn"></topbar>
</header>

<div class="middle">
    <sidebar *ngIf="userIsLoggedIn"></sidebar>
    <main>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if the login page is loaded, the topbar should be not visible. Please see again my question.

Comment: see my edit.. its your choice what is shown at the first page.. the rest should be in your MainComponent which is only available to logged in users..

Comment: I said `topbar`, not `header`. As you can see both logged and not-logged user can see `header` and `footer` sections. The logged users can see a top-menu in the header, and every pages of the app. The guest users can see only login page (that has a header and footer as well).

Comment: add that header-component to your login-component and to your main-component .. or see my edit .. there are so many ways to achieve this.. be creative! :)

Comment: You can set a property in your MainComponent called "isLoggedIn", and check it to determine if the user is logged. You can use a service to update it (loginService), and call it from other points of your app if needed.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you. But... how to prevent not-logged users to go to any forbidden path? For example if guest users type in the url bar of the browser any path that leads to certain page that is for logged users only... how to avoid this in Angular2?

Comment: There are so called `Guards` for each route, they will be executed BEFORE the Router will route them. In there you can reject and redirect them to the login-component. See official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards